# Conocer el valor de un HTMLFormElement

Tags: java, html

Necesito saver el valor de HTMLFormElement pero no logro conocerlo. Tengo este codigo :`var formularioc = document.getElementById('account').form; console.log("formularioc "+ formularioc );`
Donde lleno una variable con un objeto

y lo consulto de la siguiente manera para saber su contenido

`console.log("document--- "+  document.forms[0].elements[0] );`

Pero el resultado no me muestra el contenido del mismo

**formularioc [object HTMLFormElement]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la forma que estas haciendo con console.log(), hacelo de la siguiente forma:

```
console.log("document--- ",  document.forms[0].elements[0] );
```

Quita el **"+"** y pone **","** como lo tienes ahorita hace el el objeto se convierta en string y por eso te sale así como mencionas.

Comment: si me funciono, muchas gracias